# Problema al eliminar registros con dependencias en JSP y MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, jsp, sweetalert

Estoy intentando eliminar un registros de la base de datos mysql desde JSP
actualmente puedo eliminar registros solo si estos no tienen dependencias en otras tablas, pero cuando intento eliminar registros con dependencias, no se me muestra la excepción.

Mi Proyecto tiene las siguientes clases y archivos.

Clase EliminarReservaServlet. Esta es la clase del package control que tiene como función atender las peticiones desde el servidor para eliminar un registro.

```
  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    try
     {

        Reserva r=new Reserva();
        ReservasDao rdao=new ReservasDao();

        r.setNumeroReserva(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numReserva")));


        if(request.getParameter("numReserva")==null)
        {
            String error="Campos vacios";
        }
        else
        {
            if(request.getParameter("numReserva")!=null)
            {

                String mensajeEliminarReserva="La reserva fue eliminada satisfactoriamente";

                rdao.eliminarReservas(r);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
                    out.println("<p>No se puede eliminar la reserva debido a que tiene tramos asociados</p>");
                    System.out.println("<h2>Datos de formulario no fueron rescatados</h2>"+ex);

                }


}
```

Acá tengo la clase ReservasDao del package dao

```
public class ReservasDao {

ResultSet res;
Statement st;
PreparedStatement pst;

    public void eliminarReservas(Reserva r)
{
    String sqlEliminarReserva="";
    try
        {
            Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();

            sqlEliminarReserva="DELETE FROM RVAS WHERE COD_SEQ_RVAS='"+r.getNumeroReserva()+"';";
            st=conn.createStatement();

            st.executeUpdate(sqlEliminarReserva);


            System.out.println("Eliminada");
            st.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    catch(SQLException ex)
        {

            System.out.println(" No se puede eliminar el registro ya que existen tramos asociados a la reserva "+ ex.getMessage());

        }
}
}
```

Aca imagen de listado de registros a eliminar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al presionar el botón eliminar , se eliminan.

```
 <div id="modalReservaClienteEliminarReserva" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header btn-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h3 class="modal-title" style="color: white"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Eliminar</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
<div class="left container-fluid">
<div class="panel-heading"></div>
<div class="panel-body panel panel-warning">

             <form method="POST" action="eliminarReservaServlet.do">


                 <h4>Estás Seguro que deceas eliminar tu reserva Nº:<input type="text"  id="txt_mostrar_num_eliminar" class="input-sm" size="1" name="txt_num_reserva" readonly="readonly" style="font-size:13pt; border:0;">?</h4>

                 <br>

             </form>


</div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminarReservaAjax();mostrarReservasPorAjax()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Eliminar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cerrar </button>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Aca el codigo ajax para enviar la petición al servlet.

```
   function eliminarReservaAjax()
{

 var nreserva = $("#txt_mostrar_num_eliminar").val();

$.ajax({
  url: "eliminarReservaServlet.do",
  data: {
   numReserva : nreserva
  }
}

);


   if($("#txt_mostrar_num_eliminar").val().length >=1)
    {
        swal("Reserva eliminada con exito","","success");
    }
    else
    {
            swal({
              title: "Numero de reserva null!",
              text: "Verificar falla",
              icon: "warning"
             });


    }


}
```

Cuando intento eliminar un registro con dependencia, se muestra el mensaje de registro eliminado y obviamente el registro no se elimina pero no se muestra mensaje de validación que indique que no se puede eliminar porque el registro tiene dependencia,de hecho ese mensaje lo muestra en la consola.

El servlet EliminarReservaServlet, tiene un try{} catch(){} donde en el catch se muestra un mensaje que indica :"No se puede eliminar el registro ya que existen tramos asociados a la reserva ".
La clase ReservasDao tambien tiene un try{} catch(){} que indica el mismo mensaje.

Estos try{} cacth(){}, validan si el registro tiene dependencias.
El problema es que el que me sirve es el del servlet ya que de ahí con el método PrintWriter out , imprimo el mensaje y lo muestro en la pagina web, pero el sistema no ingresa a ese catch sino que ingresa al otro catch al de la clase ReservasDao y esa es una clase java comun y no sirve PrintWriter si no que utilizo System.out.println();.

entonces alo que voy es que al presionar el botón eliminar , si el registro no tiene dependencias , entonces se elimina correctamente, pero si tiene dependencias, el registro obviamente no se elimina pero tampoco muestra el mensaje en el modal , sino que muestra el mensaje de la clase ReservasDao en la consola.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que se puede hacer para que se muestre el mensaje del Servlet en el modal o en el mensaje de alerta de sweet alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tienes definido el método eliminarReservas puedes pensar que no se pudo borrar cuando quizás no tienes conexión de internet o conexión a la base de datos. También puedes asumir que se borró aún y cuando no haya encontrado el registro a borrar, ya que en ese caso no tira excepción porque no lo estás revisando.

Pudieras cambiar el método para que te retorne verdader o falso si lo hizo o no, y además que pueda tirar la excepción.  Algo así:

```
    /**
      retornamos verdadero solo cuando estemos seguros que se eliminó.
      y dejamos que tire la excepción si hubiera
    **/
    public boolean eliminarReservas(Reserva r) throws SQLException
    {
     String sqlEliminarReserva="";
     Connection conn = null;
     try
     {
        conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();

        sqlEliminarReserva="DELETE FROM RVAS WHERE COD_SEQ_RVAS='"+r.getNumeroReserva()+"';";
        st=conn.createStatement();

        int eliminados = st.executeUpdate(sqlEliminarReserva);

        System.out.println("Se eliminaron "+eliminados"+ registros");

        return (eliminados > 0);
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(" No se puede eliminar el registro ya que existen tramos asociados a la reserva "+ ex.getMessage());
       throw ex; /// tiramos la ex, para luego ver que tipo de ex fue.

    }
   finally {  //queremos liberar recursos y cerrar conexión aunque haya excepción
      if (st != null) {
         st.close();
      }
      if (conn != null) {
         conn.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Luego habría que cambiar el servlet:

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

try
 {

    Reserva r=new Reserva();
    ReservasDao rdao=new ReservasDao();

    r.setNumeroReserva(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numReserva")));


    if(request.getParameter("numReserva")==null)
    {
        String error="Campos vacios";
    }
    else
    {
        if(request.getParameter("numReserva")!=null)
        {

            String mensajeEliminarReserva;
            if (rdao.eliminarReservas(r)) {
                mensajeEliminarReserva = "La reserva fue eliminada satisfactoriamente";
            }
            else {
                mensajeEliminarReserva = "No se encontró la reserva indicada...";
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
           if (ex instanceof SQLException) {
              SQLException exx = (SQLException)ex;
              int codigoDeError = exx.getErrorCode();
              /*
               Ojo, con este código de error puedes revisar que tipo de error
               fue, porque puede ser de conexión, o el que tú mencionas.
               Mysql tiene una tabla de errores en su manual.

              */
           }
           PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
           out.println("<p>No se puede eliminar la reserva debido a que tiene tramos asociados</p>");

           System.out.println("<h2>Datos de formulario no fueron rescatados</h2>"+ex);

}


}
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió el código. Pero tengo una duda , como puedo hacer para que se muestre la alerta de sweet alert desde el servlet y no desde el ajax , y asi yo muestro la alerta de acuerdo al resultado de la eliminacion?, ya que me muestra el mensaje de eliminacion correcta y quiero que solo se muestre ese mensaje cuando se logra eliminar pero cuando no se logra quiero mostrar el mensaje contrario.

Comment: Todavía no conozco bien Ajax. No sabría decirte. Estoy suponiendo que necesitas pasar un texto o código como respuesta a Ajax, para que la puedas mostrar, pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: Gracias ya pude modificar y ahora se muestra la validación de sweet alert desde el servlet, ahora ya me funciona correctamente gracias.